# Radio Buttons in ListView recycling and causing issues

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

So I have a listview that is built to have each view in the list to have 2 radio buttons. The problem is when the list gets longer than the page the list starts to recycle the views and it also takes along the checked radio buttons. I understand what is causing the problem but I don't really know how to solve this issue and the answers I've looked up online aren't really helping. My problem is a bit unique because I'm using Parse with my adapter so looking up solutions specifically for parse is pretty hard.

Here is my code for my adapter:

```
    // Set up a customized query
    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost> factory =
            new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost>() {
                public ParseQuery<AnywallPost> create() {
                    Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
                    ParseQuery<AnywallPost> query = AnywallPost.getQuery();
                    query.include("user");
                    query.orderByDescending("PostScore");
                    query.whereWithinKilometers("location", geoPointFromLocation(myLoc), radius
                            * METERS_PER_FEET / METERS_PER_KILOMETER);
                    query.setLimit(MAX_POST_SEARCH_RESULTS);
                    return query;
                }
            };

    // Set up the query adapter
    postsQueryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<AnywallPost>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(AnywallPost post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.anywall_post_item, null);
            }
            //TextView DetailsView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
            TextView contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
            TextView usernameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username_view);
            TextView postscoreView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostScore);
            RadioButton upvote = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Upvote);
            RadioButton downvote = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.DownVote);

            //DetailsView.setText(post.getDetails());
            contentView.setText(post.getText());
            usernameView.setText(post.getUser().getUsername());
            postscoreView.setText(post.getInt().toString());


            upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    post.increment("PostScore", 1);
                    post.saveInBackground();
                }
            });

            downvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //post.decrement();
                }
            });


            return view;
        }
    };

    postsQueryAdapter.setAutoload(false);

    postsQueryAdapter.setPaginationEnabled(false);

    // Attach the query adapter to the view
    ListView postsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.posts_listview);
    postsListView.setAdapter(postsQueryAdapter);
```

So I need these two radio buttons to stay with the post made the entire time but I am still a beginner so I'm not entirely sure how I would go about that. Could anyone provide a solution and explain how it worked? If you need anymore code just let me know. Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially when you get a new cell, be sure to clear both the radio buttons, then re-check them only if it meets your condition for it to be checked (likely checking the count on the `post` object).  Hard to tell exactly how this will look without knowing more about how you are storing data, but I'd guess something like this:

```
upvote.setChecked(post.getInt() > 0);
downvote.setChecked(post.getInt() < 0);
```

Comment: Ok, I think I see where you are going. The getInt() returns the total points of the post made. I think what I could do is have something that records when a user has made an upvote or downvote and will only be checked if the user has previously voted on the post. Would that work?

Comment: Yeah, maybe record all things the user has upvoted in the user object, and run something like `user.upvotes.contains(postId)`

Comment: I like this idea, I'm going to try to implement it. So I have a function called up vote in my class for posts. I have it as put("upvoted", getParseObject("objectId") but I'm getting a illegalArguementException since the value I'm getting back is null. I'm pretty sure I am using the wrong call with "getParseObject("objectId")" but I don't really know another way to get the id.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the list items I'd carry a list with the state of radio buttons.
So even when the views get recycled you use your own state to check the correct radio button.

A good choice would be a list of Boolean (the boolean wrapper). Where you could keep true for upvote, false for downvote and null for neither.

Comment: Ok what I am thinking is having the post having a boolean and then the radio button would check this boolean to account for being checked or not. I think though the issue with my idea is when one person sets it to true the entire post would be set to true and not just for that user am I right with that concern?

Comment: I think you're right. Maybe keep a Map<UserId, Boolean> to check for different users.

Comment: After thinking this through. I think this should be a back-end problem. So every time you return a post (from the server) you should crosscheck it with a user. Then every post would contain a boolean (maybe enum?), about upvoting or downvoting, but it would only correspond to a single user.

Comment: Yeah I agree with that. I am working on implementing that right now but I am getting growing pains with it and having run-time errors. My problem right now is the same problem I'm having with the comment I just made below (3rd comment).